# Gradle tasks in Spring project

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, gradle

I found gradle tasks shown below in my Eclipse Java Spring project:

```
application
  bootRun
build
  assemble
  bootBuildImage
...
build setup
documentation
help
ide
verification
```

[image]
What these tasks are coming from?  Is it part of Gradle or Spring?

Comment: These are the gradle tasks for your spring project.

Comment: Where these tasks are defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) You ask

> What these tasks are coming from?

Gradle task come from 2 area: by Gradle itself and by Gradle plug-ins.

For example, at folder where has file `build.gradle` , (1a) when you run command

```
gradle bootRun
```

Spring Boot application when run, it usually run and return result at http://localhost:8080 (default). `gradle bootRun` run success by an plugin called Spring-boot-gradle-plugin declared inside `build.gradle` .

(1b) When you run

```
gradle wrapper
```

your project will add some folder and files, make your source code become portable, no need install Gradle at local PC when you share for your colleagues. `gradle wrapper` come from Gradle itself, not from third-party one.

(2) You ask

> Is it part of Gradle or Spring?

(1b) from Gradle itself, (1a) is a plug-in made by Spring team.

Reference: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-gradle-plugin

Answer (score 0):

They look to be gradle as `assemble`, `build`, `buildDependencies` are all standard irrespective of what you are building.